# Change clipped image?

Tags: javascript

```
createImage = (x=0, y=0) => {
    imgC.save()

    imgC.beginPath()
    imgC.moveTo(side/2, center)
    imgC.lineTo(side, 0)
    imgC.lineTo(0, 0)
    imgC.closePath();

    imgC.clip()

    imgC.drawImage(image, x, y)
    imgC.restore()
}
```

I'm drawing a masked image like this. I would like to update the x/y coordinates in drawImage without changing anything else. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't get it. `x` and `y` are only being used in `drawImage` anyway. What's the matter with changing those variables?

Comment: I want to map the image position to other events (like moving the cursor or tilting your phone etc)

Comment: @Himmators is right, modifying the X,Y arguments won't affect the remaining expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to do, because it seems to me that you're able to change the X,Y arguments that are passed without affecting the remaining expressions.

But, with some assumptions here's some untested code, so assume pseudo-code to understand the possibility that I'm sharing.

```
createImage = (img, x=0, y=0) => {
    img.save()

    img.beginPath()
    img.moveTo(side/2, center)
    img.lineTo(side, 0)
    img.lineTo(0, 0)
    img.closePath();

    img.clip()

    img.drawImage(image, x, y)
    img.restore()
    return img
}
```

Then you can use like:

```
var myImage = createImage(imgC, 100, 50)
```

After 3 seconds you update the X,Y

```
setTimeout(() => {
    myImage.x = 150
    myImage.y = 300
}, 3000)
```

Hope that helps!